# When using defineModel, combined with an event handler in the parent, the child does not update

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a use case where the parent component supplies some flags to the child component, and the child should be able to update its flag in the parent.

Normally you would define props and an event emitter manually, but since Vue 3.4 there is a shorthand `defineModel(...)` for this.

Consider the following parent component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import CapabilityEntry from "../components/metrics/CapabilityEntry.vue";
import {useToast} from "vue-toastification";

const toast = useToast();
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Capabilities</h1>
  <div class="space-y-5">
    <CapabilityEntry id="binaryallowed" :enabled="false" friendly-name="Binary Allowed"
                     description="Whether binary SMS content is allowed."/>
    <CapabilityEntry id="internationalallowed" :enabled="true"
                     v-on:update:enabled="toast.success('Capability updated')"/>
    <CapabilityEntry id="outboundallowed" :enabled="true"/>
    <CapabilityEntry id="inboundallowed" :enabled="true" @update:enabled="toast.success('Capability updated')"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the child component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {unref} from "vue";

defineProps({
  id: { type: String, required: true },
  friendlyName: { type: String, required: false },
  description: { type: String, required: false },
  // defaultValue: { type: Boolean, required: true }
});

const enabled = defineModel("enabled");
const defaultValue = unref(enabled);

</script>

<template>
  <div class="relative flex items-start">
    <div class="flex h-6 items-center">
      <input :id="id" aria-describedby="checked" :name="id" type="checkbox" v-model="enabled" class="h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-600 transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out" />
    </div>
    <div class="ml-3 text-sm leading-6">
      <label :for="id" class="font-medium text-gray-900">
        {{ friendlyName ? friendlyName : id }}
        <span class="inline-flex items-center rounded-md bg-gray-100 px-2 py-1 text-xs font-medium text-gray-600 transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out" v-if="enabled == defaultValue">Plan default</span>
        <span class="inline-flex items-center rounded-md bg-yellow-100 px-2 py-1 text-xs font-medium text-yellow-600 transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out" v-if="enabled != defaultValue">Deviates from plan</span>
      </label>
      <p id="comments-description" class="text-gray-500">{{description ? description : "No description"}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The expected behavior is that when the checkbox value changes from the default `defaultValue` a small badge would change color and text.

This works for the children that don't have any event handler (either `@update:enabled` or `v-on:update:enabled`), however for those that have one of these handlers, it doesn't work:

[image: A demo of the problem]

As you can observe, the `outboundallowed` checkbox works as expected and has no event handler in the parent. The `inboundallowed` does have an event handler and doesn't work.

Am I missing something here? I can't imagine I have to manually invoke an update in these event handlers?

Comment: Why are there `enabled="true""`? This will prevent two-way binding from normally working. " should be able to update its flag in the parent" - this won't happen if you don't update prop value in a parent

Comment: @EstusFlask You're totally right. I updated my example a bit to a ref boolean and call a function to update the value like so: `@update:enabled="value => capabilityFlagUpdated($el, value)"` and it works. Thanks! Still the behavior isn't consistent even if I had it wrong... Why does it work fine without an event handler?

Comment: It works in abnormal way that way, so there may be no good explanation, just unspecified behaviour